# select from t1 where count of something inside t2 is greater than zero

Tags: mysql

`t1` has `id` `status` `price`

`t2` has `id` `status` `city`

Want to select all from `t1` if `status` is `active` AND count of `t2.status = active` is greater than `0`;

Something like:

```
select id, status, price from t1 where status = 'active'
AND
count of (select status from t2 where status = 'active') > 0 order by t1.price;
```

In other words - if `active` exists in `t2.status`

Any help?

Comment: Is there any relationship at all between these 2 tables?

Answer (score 0):

i think you should explain your question more to us.
but i think this is the `Query` that you are seeking

```
SELECT TABLE1.id ,TABLE1.status ,TABLE1.price ,
if(TABLE1.status = 'active' AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
(SELECT t2.* FROM t2 WHERE stackoverflow1.t2.status = 'active' > 0) t2) ,"yes","no")
FROM t1 TABLE1 ,t2 TABLE2 GROUP BY TABLE1.price
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, status, price
FROM 
     Table1
WHERE status = 'active'
     AND EXISTS(
           SELECT status 
           FROM Table2
           WHERE status = 'active'
         )
ORDER BY price;
```